# Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl

I am a Window 8.1 user & new to ROR. Searched a lot about this... Please do a help. 
Applied tricks that did not help- https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88

Comment: This worked for me: https://gist.github.com/fnichol/867550#the-manual-way-boring

Comment: Thanks @AnandBhat  But this also giving me  "A cacert.pem bundle could not be downloaded.".. Didn't getting any thing useful for me.. Please do help..

Comment: After a long wait, now switched to **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS** with dual boot. Feeling relax & full of enthu, after-all now I can do whatever I want with _Rails + Ubuntu_ -- Great Combo..